# Lambda expression (sum of vectors)

Tags: c++, lambda

How should my lambda expression look in this case? I want to add vectors not by `std::plus<>` but using lambda.

```
MatVect add_vectors(const MatVect& v1, const MatVect& v2) 
{
    MatVect v(v1.size());

    std::transform(v1.cbegin(), v1.cend(), v2.cbegin(), v.begin(), [](){ return });

    return v;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should like this:

```
std::transform(v1.cbegin(), v1.cend(), v2.cbegin(), v.begin(), [](const int& i, const int& j){ return i + j; });
```

Minimal example:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>

using MatVect = std::vector<int>;

MatVect add_vectors(const MatVect& v1, const MatVect& v2) 
{
    MatVect v(v1.size());

    std::transform(v1.cbegin(), v1.cend(), v2.cbegin(), v.begin(), [](const int& i, const int& j){ return i + j; });

    return v;
}



int main()
{
    MatVect mv1 = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    MatVect mv2 = {2, 4, 6, 8, 10};

    MatVect mv3 = add_vectors(mv1, mv2);
    for(auto const& i : mv3)
    {
        std::cout << i << " ";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

See Live Demo [here](https://wandbox.org/permlink/0LyoEdYr6UYHhvQM).

Comment: Only a small comment, but your function only works if MatVect contains `int`. I would replace the `int` by `auto`

Comment: I chose `int` because `auto` with types that do not have `+` defined for them would have a wrong result. Example a vector of `char`s. Anyway it is a minimal example. The OP can change to fit their needs.

Answer (score 1):

I would try something like the following

```
MatVect add_vectors(MatVect const &v1, MatVect const &v2) 
{
    MatVect v(size(v1));

    std::transform(std::cbegin(v1), std::cend(v1), std::cbegin(v2), std::begin(v), 
                  [](auto const lhs, auto const rhs)
                  { 
                    return lhs + rhs;
                  });
    return v;
}
```

The remaining question is, why not using the `std::plus<>`?

Comment: @Hiroki Good question, that must have been a 'typo'.